# Automaapper fails to map few fields. And enter null values to those fields

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, automapper

When i retrieve the data from table using LINQ all the columns have values. But After i Map it to my model some fields are mapped as null.The strange part is this is not happening with all the tables

This is the code

```
var city = db.tbl_city.ToList();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<tbl_city, ModelCities>();
var CityVieModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<tbl_city>, List<ModelCities>>(city);
```

Code for custom model

```
 public class ModelCities
   {
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }

   }
```

Code for table city in edmx is

```
 public partial class tbl_city
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tbl_city()
    {
        this.tbl_areas = new HashSet<tbl_areas>();
    }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Cityame { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsAlias { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tbl_areas> tbl_areas { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_state tbl_state { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your tbl_city class there is the following property

```
public string Cityame { get; set; }
```

the name of the property is not correct, and according to the hat the Automapper will fail mapping the properties because it is depend on the name of the properties to establish the mapping, Fix this property name as the following

```
public string CityName { get; set; }
```